# Numpy - Apply a custom function on all combination of rows in matrix to get a new matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following function, that applies the histogram intersection kernel for 2 arrays:

```
def histogram_intersection_kernel(X, Y):

k = np.array([])
for x_i,y_i in zip(X,Y):
    k = np.append(k,np.minimum(x_i,y_i))
return np.sum(k)
```

now, lets say I have the following matrix "mat":

```
[[1,0,0,2,3],
[2,3,4,0,1],
[3,3,5,0,1]]
```

I would like to find an **efficient** way to get the matrix that is the result of applying "histogram_intersection_kernel" to all of the combinations of rows in mat. In this example it would be:

```
[[6,2,2],
[6,10,10],
[2,10,12]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend dimensions to `3D` and leverage [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
np.minimum(a[:,None,:],a[None,:,:]).sum(axis=2)
```

Or simply -

```
np.minimum(a[:,None],a).sum(2)
```

Sample run -

```
In [248]: a
Out[248]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4, 0, 1],
       [3, 3, 5, 0, 1]])

In [249]: np.minimum(a[:,None],a).sum(2)
Out[249]: 
array([[ 6,  2,  2],
       [ 2, 10, 10],
       [ 2, 10, 12]])
```

Comment: Will you mind to explain why a[:,None] results in dimensions (3,1,5) and not (3,5,1) ? I am familiar with what "None" does but never used it myself on 2d arrays.

Comment: @MoranReznik `None` being an alias for `numpy.newaxis` adds a new axis of length = 1 there. So, with `a[:,None,:]`, we would have : `(3,1,5)`. Does that make sense? That broadcasting link should have more info.

Comment: Im aware of why [:,None,:] resulsts in (3,1,5). just not why a[:,None] results in (3,1,5)?

Comment: @MoranReznik Ah, `[:,None,:]` is same as `[:,None]`. For indexing we can skip the trailing colons.

Comment: Google search gives no information about what "trailing colons" are. Will you care to elaborate ?

Comment: @MoranReznik Read this - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays